# TCP Connection Stops Working

Tags: c#, tcp, irc

I'm working on an IRC implementation in C#.  My work is based off of IRC.NET, and I have this problem that keeps cropping up.  According to wireshark, my session is almost identical to X-Chat, where the problem does not occur.  The problem in question is that after about 10 minutes of perfect operation, it stops working out of nowhere.  No exceptions occur, but the bot is unable to send messages and sees nothing from the server.  I respond to pings and such appropriately.  After a while, the server (FreeNode) reports that the bot has pinged out, but the client knows nothing of it.

It is a very frustrating bug, and I have no idea what is causing it.

EDIT:

Here are some relevant links:

[Library my work is based on](https://github.com/alexreg/ircdotnet) (I have made very few changes)

The bulk of the relevant code is in [IrcClient.cs](https://github.com/alexreg/ircdotnet/blob/master/src/IrcDotNet/IrcClient.cs)

Here's most of my code for working against the library: [Link](https://gist.github.com/c22b0f3f5e617c656784)

Comment: Sounds very much like a buffer overflow. Can you reduce it to the constituent parts that reproduce the bug and no more code? You can link to a github repo or gist (http://gist.github.com) if you like.

Comment: We definitely need to see some code to answer this type of question, specifically how you handle your connections.?

Comment: I updated my question with some links.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered that it might be due to garbage collection? It would be good to see if you can establish whether or not your `server` or `timer` objects are being collected

Comment: I updated the code so that the garbage collector won't pick it up.  Same problem occurs.  Even stranger, I get an internal Mono error if I try to cycle the connection.